# test if Three.js is supported

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js

I'd like to find a way to test if the browser can support three.js. I saw that you can use a detector.js provided by three.js with this line of code to check whether you should use WebGL or canvas :

```
renderer = Detector.webgl? new THREE.WebGLRenderer(): new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
```

That's a part of job not the whole of it. CanvasRenderer doesn't work with every other browser. Depending what you want to do. In my case, I want to do a simple spinning cube like the canvas example provided by three.js), it doesn't work on IE9, even if IE9 is supposed to support canvas (http://caniuse.com/canvas).

I'd like to be able to test if the browsers supports the example code or not. I don't want to check every browser one by one and see if they can support it and then, show something else if they don't.

Any idea is welcome. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an additionnal test to check if the browser support Canvas, it's in Detector.js (Detector.canvas) :

```
!! window.CanvasRenderingContext2D
```

But the problem with IE9 (and may be 10, I don't know) is not due to that, it's due to the loading sequence wich is asynchronous. You need to use [Require.js](http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html) or simply [something like that](http://books.google.fr/books?id=ED6ph4WEIoQC&lpg=PP1&dq=high%20performance%20javascript&pg=PA11&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) to load three.min.js and other scripts, and then it will work. You can also check [iewegl examples](http://iewebgl.com/Developer.aspx) to see how they do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I haven't notice Detector.canvas, thank you to point it me out. I wasn't aware about Require.js or something similiar, so i tried to use it, but it doesn't seem to work better on IE9. I put an exemple online if you want to check it:http://mywholepicture.com/test/detector.html

Comment: As you wrote, I've used this line to check if the browser can render the cube :`if(!Detector.webgl && !Detector.canvas)`

Comment: [I would try something like that](http://jsfiddle.net/jeum/t52p5/) but I can't test it. I have updated IE, but there was a solution for IE9 (I used my 2nd link). Otherwise your message could also be "Please upadate your browser ..." With IE11 you don't need to change the usual script and you'll get webgl.

Comment: I haven't find a way which works at 100%, not sure there's one though. At the end, i will use a link that user can use to switch the 3D preview into pseudo 3d images. It's the better way I found how to deal with this issue. Thank you for your help

Comment: [Try this one](http://jsfiddle.net/jeum/t52p5/7/) (I remembered something), if it still doesn't work I don't know :(